# how to label my equations with Latex in macOS Pages?

Tags: equations, labels, macos

G'day, mate. I'm writing my paper, but I don't know how to label my equations.
I typed `\label{(1.1)}`(1.2,1.3,…etc.) after my equation, but it always doesn't work! I tried `\ref{}` as well, it doesn’t work neither.
Maybe Pages doesn't support this syntax?
Hope someone can help me out. Thanks.[image]

Comment: Your question is very unclear. `\label{abc}` makes no visible output but sets `abc` as an internal identifier so `\ref{abc}` will reference the equation.  I doubt this does anything useful if you extract just an equation image in to another application, which is what Pages is doing I think (I don't have a mac)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "label my equations". Perhaps you are after something like `a = 2b   eq.3` Please show the typed output you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry, sir. I just uploaded a picture showing my Latex codes. I tried `\ref{}` too, but it didn’t work. By the way, Pages is iWork application which is like Word in Windows system.

Comment: In LaTeX, you would have `\label{myequation}` in the equation, and refer to it later with `\ref{myequation}` (numbering defeats that purpose entirely).  If that doesn't work, you could try `\tag{(1.1)}` within the equation.  If that doesn't work, you could take a manual approach `\qquad{\rm(1.1)}`.

Comment: @PeterWilson hello, outputs I want are just like all formulas and equations you see in any physics textbook.`F=ma     (1.1)` or `W=mg.    (1.2)`. Each formula or equation has a number aligned to its right.

Comment: it looks like you are expecting `\label`   to print (1.1) it would not do that in latex, it produces no output. In the blahtex you are using it probably does nothing, just use `(1.1)` to print 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Pages (and other Apple applications) support MathML and a subset of the latex syntax (not latex itself) for math using [Blahtex](http://gva.noekeon.org/blahtexml/blahtexml-0.9-doc.pdf). And it looks like `\label` is not supported. For more information see the documentation here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202501